# kill bash script with wait command

Tags: shell, timeout, wait

A bash script `demo.sh`

`#!/bin/bash
./prog1 &
./prog2 &
wait`

Use `timeout -s 9 5m demo.sh` to run the script.

The script demo.sh used to be without `&` and `wait`. I want to know whether `timeout` will kill prog1 and prog2 when timeout happens. How can I make sure that all subprocesses would be killed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forked jobs will be killed when you kill the shell process started by
`demo.sh` (unless you do something like `disown $PID`).

You can ensure this happens with `kill -0`:

```
./prog1 &
echo P1=$!
./prog2 &
echo P2=$!
```

you can then `kill -0 ${PID1}` and `kill -0 ${PID2}` and ensure that both
commands return with exit status `1`, which means "couldn't find process"